# populate following users mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Lemme take time to explain what is happening from start to finish.

**Preamble**:

A user a follows 10 other people. When user A logs in, an X number of posts from each of the 10 people are pulled into view.

I do not know if it is the right thing to do, and will appreciate a better way of doing it. However, I wanna give it a try, and it ain't working.

**Follow Model**:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let FollowSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  followers: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Card'
  }],
  following: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Card'
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Follow', FollowSchema);
```

**Card Model**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let CardSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  createdById: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Card', CardSchema);
```

**Follow logic**

When user A follows user B, do two things:

- Push the user_id of B to user A document on field 'following' (A is following B)
- Push user_id of A to user B document on field 'followers' (B is followed by A)

  ```
  router.post('/follow', utils.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  const user_id = req.user._id;
  const follow = req.body.follow_id;

  let bulk = Follow.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

  bulk.find({ 'user': Types.ObjectId(user_id) }).upsert().updateOne({
      $addToSet: {
          following: Types.ObjectId(follow)
      }
  });

  bulk.find({ 'user': Types.ObjectId(follow) }).upsert().updateOne({
      $addToSet: {
          followers: Types.ObjectId(user_id)
      }
  })

  bulk.execute(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
          return res.json({
              'state': false,
              'msg': err
          })
      }
      res.json({
          'state': true,
          'msg': 'Followed'
      })
  })
  ```

  })

**Actual DB values**

```
> db.follows.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e3e27dace1f14e0a70862d"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59e2194177cae833894c9956"),
    "following" : [
        ObjectId("59e3e618ace1f14e0a708713")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e3e27dace1f14e0a70862e"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59e13b2dca5652efc4ca2cf5"),
    "followers" : [
        ObjectId("59e2194177cae833894c9956"),
        ObjectId("59e13b2d27cfed535928c0e7"),
        ObjectId("59e3e617149f0a3f1281e849")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e3e71face1f14e0a708770"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59e13b2d27cfed535928c0e7"),
    "following" : [
        ObjectId("59e3e618ace1f14e0a708713"),
        ObjectId("59e13b2dca5652efc4ca2cf5"),
        ObjectId("59e21942ca5652efc4ca30ab")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e3e71face1f14e0a708771"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59e3e618ace1f14e0a708713"),
    "followers" : [
        ObjectId("59e13b2d27cfed535928c0e7"),
        ObjectId("59e2194177cae833894c9956")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e3e72bace1f14e0a708779"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59e21942ca5652efc4ca30ab"),
    "followers" : [
        ObjectId("59e13b2d27cfed535928c0e7"),
        ObjectId("59e2194177cae833894c9956"),
        ObjectId("59e3e617149f0a3f1281e849")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f0eef155ee5a5897e1a66d"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59e3e617149f0a3f1281e849"),
    "following" : [
        ObjectId("59e21942ca5652efc4ca30ab"),
        ObjectId("59e13b2dca5652efc4ca2cf5")
    ]
}
>
```

With the above database results, this is my query:

**Query**

```
router.get('/follow/list', utils.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
    const user_id = req.user._id;

    Follow.findOne({ 'user': Types.ObjectId(user_id) })
      .populate('following')
      .exec(function(err, doc) {
          if (err) {
              return res.json({
                  'state': false,
                  'msg': err
              })
          };

          console.log(doc.username);

          res.json({
              'state': true,
              'msg': 'Follow list',
              'doc': doc
          })
      })
});
```

With the above query, from my little understanding of Mongoose populate, I expect to get cards from each of the Users in the `following` array.

My understanding and expectations might be wrong, however with such an endgoal, is this populate approach okay? Or am I trying to solve an aggregation task with population?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answer. Getting quite close, but still, the `followingCards` array contains no result. Here's the contents of my current `Follow` model:

```
> db.follows.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f24c0555ee5a5897e1b23d"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59f24bda1d048d1edad4bda8"),
    "following" : [
        ObjectId("59f24b3a55ee5a5897e1b1ec"),
        ObjectId("59f24bda55ee5a5897e1b22c")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f24c0555ee5a5897e1b23e"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59f24b3a55ee5a5897e1b1ec"),
    "followers" : [
        ObjectId("59f24bda1d048d1edad4bda8")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f24c8855ee5a5897e1b292"),
    "user" : ObjectId("59f24bda55ee5a5897e1b22c"),
    "followers" : [
        ObjectId("59f24bda1d048d1edad4bda8")
    ]
}
>
```

Here are all the current content I have from `Card` Model:

```
> db.cards.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f24bc01d048d1edad4bda6"),
    "title" : "A day or two with Hubtel's HTTP API",
    "content" : "a day or two",
    "external" : "",
    "slug" : "a-day-or-two-with-hubtels-http-api-df77056d",
    "createdBy" : "seanmavley",
    "createdById" : ObjectId("59f24b391d048d1edad4bda5"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-26T20:55:28.293Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f24c5f1d048d1edad4bda9"),
    "title" : "US couple stole goods worth $1.2m from Amazon",
    "content" : "for what",
    "external" : "https://bbc.com",
    "slug" : "us-couple-stole-goods-worth-dollar12m-from-amazon-49b0a524",
    "createdBy" : "nkansahrexford",
    "createdById" : ObjectId("59f24bda1d048d1edad4bda8"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-26T20:58:07.793Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

With the Populate Virtual example from yours (@Veeram), here's the response I get:

```
{"state":true,"msg":"Follow list","doc":{"_id":"59f24c0555ee5a5897e1b23d","user":"59f24bda1d048d1edad4bda8","following":["59f24b3a55ee5a5897e1b1ec","59f24bda55ee5a5897e1b22c"],"followers":[],"id":"59f24c0555ee5a5897e1b23d","followingCards":[]}}
```

The `followingCards` array is empty.

Using the `$lookup` query on the other hand simply returns `[]`

I'm likely missing something?

Comment: Edit your question with your schemas.

Comment: @JohnnyHK ok. will do.

Comment: populate only works if you pushed refs to Follow.following before saving !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either virtual populate or `$lookup` operator in aggregation pipeline.

Using Virtual Populate

```
FollowSchema.virtual('followingCards', {
    ref: 'Card',
    localField: 'following',
    foreignField: 'createdById'
});

Follow.findOne({ 
   'user': Types.ObjectId(user_id) })
   .populate('followingCards')
   .exec(function(err, doc) {      
      console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

Using `$lookup` aggregation

```
Follow.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "user": Types.ObjectId(user_id) 
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "cards",
      "localField": "following",
      "foreignField": "createdById",
      "as": "followingCards"
    }
  }
]).exec(function (err, doc) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried your approaches. The `followingCards` array is then part of the response object, however the array contains an empty list. Please see updated question for actual values in DB currently.

Comment: Np. Can you add the `mongoose.set('debug', true);` at the top of the file to see what queries get sent to mongodb ? Btw I have fixed the lookup to include the correct collection name `cards`. Can you also try lookup aggregation without the match stage to check if it works and then you can put it back ?

Comment: The `following` array field values in the `follows` collections doesn't have a matching `createdById` in the `cards` colleciton. Try using the `followers` field instead for the data that you have provided and you can adjust the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema

var eventSchema = Schema({
title     : String,
location  : String,
startDate : Date,
endDate   : Date
});

var personSchema = Schema({
firstname: String,
lastname: String,
email: String,
dob: Date,
city: String,
eventsAttended: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }]
});

var Event  = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

To show how populate is used, first create a person object,

```
   aaron = new Person({firstname: 'Aaron'}) and an event object, 
   event1 = new Event({title: 'Hackathon', location: 'foo'}):

   aaron.eventsAttended.push(event1);
   aaron.save(callback);
```

Then, when you make your query, you can populate references like this:

```
 Person
.findOne({ firstname: 'Aaron' })
.populate('eventsAttended') .exec(function(err, person) {
if (err) return handleError(err);
console.log(person);
 });
```

// only works if we pushed refs to person.eventsAttended

Answer (score 0):

note: change Activity.find to Card.find

```
const { ObjectID } = require("mongodb");
// import Follow and Activity(Card) schema

const userId = req.tokenData.userId; // edit this too...
Follow.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user: ObjectID(userId)
    }
  }
])
.then(data => {
  // console.log(data)
  var dataUsers = data[0].following.map(function(item) {
    return item._id;
  });
  // console.log(dataUsers)
  Activity.find(
    { createdById: { $in: dataUsers } },
    {
      _id: 1,
      title: 1,
      content: 1,
      createdBy: 1,
      creatorAvatar: 1,
      activityType: 1,
      createdAt: 1
    }
  )
    // .sort({createdAt:-1)
    .then(posts => res.send({ posts }));
});
```